# C# DataGridView unable to select cells

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView (DGV) that is NOT using data binding The data is in a SQLite DB
I have written a method that styles the DataGridView
I can populate the DGV with the id of the records in the DB and two string variables
For testing I have 4 TextBox's on the form when I click on the cells I would like to 
retrieve the id to transfer that value to another form to use in SQL search
I have tried a number of methods to get data by clicking on the DGV all three are in the 
posted code NO I DO NOT WANT to use data binding
SIDE NOTE I have this code working in a VB.Net application no issues
I am new to C# so the code conversion may be the real issue
**SO the question is Using C# How to click on a DGV and retrieve the selected value?**

```
    public partial class frmSelect : Form
{
    string gv_parentInt = "";
    string gv_firstName = "";
    string gv_lastName = "";
    public frmSelect()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void frmSelect_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StyleDGV();
        readFriendsData();  
    }

    // Thried these two methods below NO RESULTS
   /* private void dgvPerson_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            tbID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            tbFName.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            tbLName.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }
    }*/

    /*public void dgvPerson_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
        { 
        tbMessage.Text = dgvPerson.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
        }
    }*/

    public void dgvPerson_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex == -1)
        {
            tbMessage.Text = "Col " + e.ColumnIndex + " ROW " + e.RowIndex;// for testing
            tbMessage.Text = "No Clicking Here";
            //return;
        }
        string strFName;
        string strLName;

        DataGridViewRow row = dgvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            strFName = dgvPerson.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            if (strFName != " ")
            {
                if (strFName == " ")
                    return;
                int intId = System.Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
                gv_parentInt = intId.ToString();
                tbID.Text = gv_parentInt;

                strFName = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                gv_firstName = strFName.Trim();
                tbFName.Text = gv_firstName;

                strLName = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                gv_lastName = strLName.Trim();
                tbLName.Text = gv_lastName;
            }
        
    tbMessage.Text = "No Data Here";
}
    private void readFriendsData()
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{"Contacts.db"}';Version=3;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            // The $ sign and '{String or Integer}' how to add variable to SQL Select Statement'gv_parentInt
            // Must incorparate BOTH for SELECT to work
            // =================================================================================
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand($"SELECT * FROM FriendsData", conn))
            {
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        gv_parentInt = rdr["FID"].ToString().Trim();
                        gv_firstName = rdr["fxFirstName"].ToString().Trim();
                        gv_lastName = rdr["fxLastName"].ToString().Trim();
                        dgvPerson.Rows.Add(gv_parentInt, gv_firstName, gv_lastName);
                    }
                    rdr.Close();
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        //frmPrintLabel.LoadLabel();
    }

    public void StyleDGV()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(dgvPerson);
        // Set Design of the DataGridView
        dgvPerson.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Bold Tahoma", 11);
        dgvPerson.ColumnCount = 3;
        dgvPerson.Columns[0].Width = 60;
        dgvPerson.Columns[1].Width = 138;
        dgvPerson.Columns[2].Width = 138;

        // To Set Col Header Size Mode = Enabled
        // To Set Col Header Default Cell Styles DO in Properties

        dgvPerson.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        dgvPerson.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;

        dgvPerson.ColumnHeadersHeight = 34;

        // DGV Header Names
        dgvPerson.Columns[0].Name = "  ID";
        dgvPerson.Columns[1].Name = "First Name";
        dgvPerson.Columns[2].Name = "Last Name";
        dgvPerson.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font("Bold Tahoma", 11);
        dgvPerson.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font("Bold Tahoma", 11);
        dgvPerson.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font("Bold Tahoma", 11);
        dgvPerson.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        dgvPerson.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        dgvPerson.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        dgvPerson.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        dgvPerson.Columns[1].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        dgvPerson.Columns[2].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
    }

    private void btnReturn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
        frmStart fST = new frmStart();
        fST.Show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First let me say that using the TOOL from a VB.Net project was a BIG 4 hour mistake
Here is the code I used to capture the values in the DataGridView

```
    private void dgvPerson_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int ID = 0;// Declare this top level 
        ID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        tbID.Text = ID.ToString();
        tbFName.Text = dgvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        tbLName.Text = dgvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Here is what was WRONG Visual Studio 2019 has two DataGridView Tools
One under All Windows Forms and one under Data (see attached screen shot)
I used the one under All Windows Form in the ToolBox hence my code FAILED
**Use the DGV under Data in the ToolBox if your are working with C# and SQLite**
[image: This is the wrong one for C#]
[image: Use this if your working with C#]